# Infinite scroll loads end of page upon visiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I implemented this "Infinite Scroll" plugin (Paul Irish one).

Though i've stumbled upon a problem, the plugin loads finishedMsg upon visiting the page without even moving the page and if you scroll fast enough you can see the "Next/Prev" buttons disappear and the message appearing before it disappears as well.

```
$('.infinite').infinitescroll({
loading: {
    finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
    msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>"
},
debug: false,
nextSelector: ".page-navigation span.prev a",
navSelector: '.page-navigation span a',
extraScrollPx: 0,
appendCallback: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the entire thing and instead I implemented a `Position:fixed` in CSS to make my own Next/Previous.